# Updating specifc user row after 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a Event (As far as my research that it is suitable). I wanna update the specifc row of a specific user.
For example.
I have a user who has the 50 coins default.
I need a logic to know how can I update 50 to 60 just after 24 hours. I tried to make my own login but I was stuck at many things, like how will I compare the user date and time and check if its been 24 hours. How can I add the WHERE condition in the CREATE EVENT.
MY CODE

```
$user_table = $username . '_msgs';
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(username,password,online,profile,status,bio,b_coin)VALUES('$username','$password','0','N/A','N/A','N/A','10')");
    mysqli_query($con, "CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO
  UPDATE users SET b_coin = b_coin + 1 WHERE username='$name'");    
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
       <a href="../login" class="alert-link" style="text-align:center;">Registered! Click Here!
    </div>';
```

Comment: @JasonK do I have to put the code in the login form? Like if the users login then the event will be created?

Comment: Why change anything in the table when you don't select it? Just calculate the coins when you query the table.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html Your sql will go under the DO section. Call it from where ever you want.

Comment: @JasonK So I dont have to compare with the users current date and time?

Comment: I can't really answers those questions for you. You need to think about when you want things to happen.

Comment: @Dharman This is just for my practice purpose but yeah I will surely do that Thank You

Comment: There is no need to learn the worst way possible. Prepared statements are simpler and the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks a bit confusing, in my opinion. Do you want to update the coins every 24 hours of all registered players? If so, I can think of two approachs to be followed:

1. **Database event:** You can create a database event that runs every 24 hours and add 10 coins into every registered player into your system. For that, you don't need to do this in the moment player is registered, you can do it directly into your database.

**Reference link:** http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

2. **PHP script:** You can create a PHP script that execute a query to update all users coins. So, in the server you considering to run the application, you configure a crontab to run every 24 hours and execute the update for you.

**Reference link:** https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide

In my personal opinion, I'd go for the **1st** solution, which sounds to make more sense to this kind of problem.

Comment: Thank You! But Im still confused with adding the WHERE condition

Comment: Basically, you already have the WHERE condition working the way you need. The event with the query, you gotta run the CREATE EVENT... query to create the event in your database, not in your code (not sure if it's clear for you). So, with the query

UPDATE users SET coin = coin + 10; should work fine for  you.

Now, you just need to understand how to create a database event that runs every 24 hours (or any other time makes sense for your application).

For database event reference, I'd take a look in this question, looks pretty clear for me. Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Question reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733433/how-to-create-an-event-that-runs-every-24-hours